# Can user authorization be set on a per-controller basis in web.config? (cannot use AuthorizeAttribute)

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API 2 app using windows auth. I have multiple controllers and this in my web.config for authorization:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="AllowedUsersAndGroups" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <sessionState mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
```

This "blanket" authorization works great, **but I have 2 specific controllers that I need to lock down differently: I want to specify different users that are authorized to hit these 2 controllers**.

The obvious answer would be to use the `[Authorize()]` attribute on the controller classes, however I cannot use this attribute because I am using per-environment (Dev-UAT-Prod) XML transforms to the web.config and need to be able to change which users are authorized on these controllers in each environment.

So, is it possible to specify authorization for individual controllers in my web.config file?

I am open to other solutions as long as they allow for Authorizing different users when the app is deployed in each environment (dev-uat-prod).

Thanks!

Comment: In our environment we created a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that derives from the base attribute. In it we check for per environment roles. I'll  look up an example.

Comment: It'd be great if you could post an example - I'm currently looking into AuthorizeAttribute so any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our environment we use this approach:

The names of Active Directory groups are stored in the app-settings. These names are different per environment.

Next we created a subtype of `AuthorizeAttribute` called `AuthorizeWritersAttribute` like this:

```cs
public class AuthorizeWritersAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    public AuthorizeWritersAttribute()
    {
        Roles = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SolutionName:AuthorizedWriters"];
        // Actually we removed the dependency on ConfigurationManager but for brevity this suffices.
    }
}
```

Finally we apply this attribute to our controllers:

```cs
[AuthorizeWriters]
public class BlogController : Controller
{
    ....
}
```

We use AD-groups but AD-accounts should work as well.

Comment: Excellent - this was precisely what I was looking for! <br>Instead of `ConfigurationManager`, I just changed to `Settings.Default.SpecialControllerAuthorizedUsers;` so that the setting is placed with the others in `web.config` (rather than in the `<appSettings>` section)