# Access controller and methods by dynamic validation in asp.net Mvc5

Tags: c#

As everyone knows that we can access controller by role name in default security system of asp.net Mvc5 application.
But when we set role name on top of the controller for authorization , its hardcoded its not dynamic. 
So i want to set authorization by controller name and also methods. Thats why i have designed a table that have some column like : controller name , isEditable,isDeleteae,roleid 
Now i want to authorize on top of the controller by controller name. Not using role name.
Can anyone help me!

Comment: can you post some of your code i don't quite understand your solution so far

Comment: I suspect you could solve this using a custom AuthorizeAttribute as suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871893/can-user-authorization-be-set-on-a-per-controller-basis-in-web-config-cannot-u)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `AuthorizeAttribute` to create your custom Authorization attribute which can be added into filter config. Override AuthorizeCore and HandleUnauthorizedRequest methods to customize your application requirement.

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)

 protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext context)
```